# Why can't I submit portals any longer?

Tags: ingress

I've been playing Ingress for ~2 years. I have 70 portals approved. I play on a new-ish Android phone (oneplus one, cyanogenmod). I've always been able to submit a portal by turning on auto-sync, then, within the game, long-pressing on my scanner, then sliding right to select "create portal".

I'm on version 1.81.0 of the app. I was able to submit as recently as August 26. IIRC, I did get an update to Android 5.1.1 recently, though I'm not sure if that was the point at which I could no longer submit a new portal.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

NIA has disabled it temporarily, because they are swamped.

See this post: https://plus.google.com/+NIAOps/posts/HfrZxjvjjdU

Comment: For the record, note that their post was on September 2nd 2015, and the commentary suggests that they have made little or no progress since then as of early 2016

Answer (score 4):

Niantic (if you follow the link in Maerlyn's answer) says they are reworking the portal submission and edit approval system.

We can expect some kind of voting system allowing players taking part in the approval, but it's not easy to implement without allowing factions to consider it as a sub-game where you create portals useful for you and remove the one used by opponents.

They are much less overwhelmed by portal submissions since they have disabled the seer medal. Submission of good quality portals in place where portal density is low were often approved in a few days.